# Neo4j dump fails with integer overflow error

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-admin

I have a large neo4j database of size more than 1 TB. I was using `dump` and `load` for backup and restore process. `dump` was working fine while my database size was less than 1 TB, but after it reached 1 TB `dump` is failing with error message "Failed to dump database integer overflow".

I couldn't find any solution for this.

I need to run neo4j-admin `dump` process successfully.

Comment: You should probably submit an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) for this.